# tvos: How should we handle low resolution monitor? like 1366x768

Tags: uiview, tvos, apple-tv

Original question is: 
tvos: Why is full screen UIView actually beyond visual bounds of the main screen on real TV monitor?

On tvos, the root UIView size is 1920x1080 by default on storyboard, which is full screen I believe. My issue is when I run it on tvos simulator, I see it perfectly shown in full screen, but when I run it on real apple TV device with a HD monitor connected, I see the UIView is beyond the visual bounds of the monitor screen on all 4 edges, with margin =~ 44px

I have to move subview contents towards center to make all of them fully appear on TV monitor.

I suspect this might be a monitor adaptability issue, but I tried this on 3 HD TV monitors (1080p), they all show the same problem.

Does anyone see this issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I just checked the local resolution of all the 3 monitors and found it is actually only 1366x768, much smaller than tvos's 1920x1080
This made me even more confused that there should be a whole lot of portion of the UIView being outside of the low resolution monitor: 277px on left/right edge, but actually it is only about 44px.

I tried UIView's different modes as well, Scale to Fill, Aspect Fit, Center... all same!!

And, I notice tvos native views like home screen, movies screens, app store screens, they all perfectly fit my low resolution monitors.

Please help, how should I deal with this issue?

BTW, does apple tv / tvos has the ability to detect monitor's native resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After play around with TV monitors for a while, I figured out that most monitors have a display mode feature for users to choose, like 16:9 movie / game / computer / etc, when I choose computer, I see tvos app shown in full screen perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. What I did is to just make my UIView adjusts it's bounds x+=50, y+=30, then the width-=100, height-=60.. subtract width and height with *2 of x and y... hope this helps..